# Python linking two projects in same solutions with 'from ... import *'

Tags: python, import

In the same solution I have my project which imports SQL and my game project.
Unfortunately when I type "from highscore import *" it doesn't recognize it in the game file. 
Am I missing something important?

Comment: Please add your code attempts and your solution hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is considered bad practice to use `import *`.
You're better off importing only the things you need with `from highscore import score` or `import highscore`.

> [What are the “best practices” for using import in a module?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-import-in-a-module)
>
> In general, don’t use from modulename import *. Doing so clutters the importer’s namespace, and makes it much harder for linters to detect undefined names.

Comment: I've thought about that but the problem is it doesn't recognize 'highscore' while it's in the same solution.

Comment: Be sure to create a `__init__.py` file in the directory.